# Why does canvas shape only render on the last canvas out of 3?

Tags: javascript, canvas

As seen on my jsfiddle, i have 3 canvases that is rendering one shape however it only renders on the last canvas. I guess i might be missing something however i have looped over the canvas elements so i thought it would just work on all of them. I am new to Javascript so sorry if its silly thinking.

```
var c = document.getElementsByClassName("myCanvas");

for (var canvas of c) {

var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(150, 0, 3, 75);

var img = new Image();
img.src = "https://assets.servedby-buysellads.com/p/manage/asset/id/26625";
img.onload = function() {
    var pattern = ctx.createPattern(this,"repeat");
    ctx.fillStyle = pattern;
    ctx.fill();
};
ctx.closePath();

}
```

My Fiddle:

[Here is my JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/89jqnqod/)

Comment: The onload does not run until after the for loop is complete execution is complete . Then the onload runs and ctx will be the last context on the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you get from `getElementsByClassName` is an [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) and not an object, so you loop through them in the same way you would loop through an array.

You where trying to loop through it using `for (var canvas of c)` which should be `for (var canvas in c)` if it was an object. But as mentioned before, what you have is not an object.

Then, you need to consider that the `onload` function on an image is async. Since you are using the same image for all of them, it would be ok to load the image once and then paint all canvases after image is loaded.

```
var c = document.getElementsByClassName("myCanvas");
// First load the image
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
  // Once the image is ready, loop through the HTMLCollection
  for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
    var canvas = c[i];
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var pattern = ctx.createPattern(img, "repeat");
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(150, 0, 3, 75);
    ctx.fillStyle = pattern;
    ctx.fill();
  }
};
img.src = "https://assets.servedby-buysellads.com/p/manage/asset/id/26625";
```